# Django: Best practice for importing views in urls file

Tags: python, django

I've read in a book that you should avoid doing this:

```
from .views import *
```

What I am currently doing is the following:

```
from . import views
```

My first question is, if this is the same thing just written differently?

My second question is if I should import it this way above or should I import every view separately?

```
from .views import (DetailView, EditView, DeleteView,
                    ListView, AnotherView, OneMoreView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean it is bad practice because you import everything, even if you do not use it. If you have helper functions in your views, it imports those as well. If you go with the second option you must use the prefix `views.` before any view function/class. This can be a nuisance, therefore you should just import each view you would like to use, then you can just call the view.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same thoughts, but I was not sure about this ^^

Comment: Glad I could help you.